# Was the knife cut tool changed?

Tags: knife-tool

Did knife cut tool change its behavior from 2.5 to 2.76?

I noticed, that [in Blender tutorial](https://vimeo.com/44840704), the behavior of Knife Cut tool is described differently, than I see.

[image]

Particularly, in "exact cut mode" (left) Neal Hirsig demonstrates that triangular faces created at the sides of selected edges. Also he demonstrates, how "midpoint mode" works (right).

At my Blender I have

[image]

that <kbd>K</kbd> mode does not create triangular faces, while <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> mode does not work at all.

Did behavior actually changed? Or I am just in different mode?

Comment: Knife tool creates N-gons, if you want to create triangles after using the Knife tool, select the N-gon in face selection mode and hit Ctrl+T shortcut.

Comment: Was this changed since 2.5? Or I turned some mode ON?

Comment: N-gons were added in early 2.6 versions.

Comment: And why doesn't `Shift-K` working as in tutorial?

Comment: Shift+K limits the cuts to selected faces only, you can enable or disable that in the operator panel after competing Knife Tool operation.

Comment: Here is the full manual http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html

Comment: Is it possible to call "midpoint knife" in modern Blender?

Comment: A quick looks shows that that tutorial was 3 years ago, seeing Blender is constantly under development, highly likely.